# Changing the color of a parent div to the color of active child element on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-color

Pretty much what's written above, I want to change the color of the container div so that it reflects the color of specific selected active elements.

So for example, the container's background is a shade of grey - when I click on the element, the element contains a blue background. I want that blue background to then fill the grey element. And so on and so forth with different selected elements and colors. I only included one element, but at least 4 more elements will need this coding.

I imagine this needs to be done with Javascript? I have seen solutions for on hover and they required JS.

```css
#tabTopBar {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

.tabTop {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: gray;
}

.tabTop a {
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

#armory.active {
    background-color: #0e343d;
    color: white;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#armory:hover {
    background-color: #879a9e;
    color: black;
}

#peerless.active {
    background-color: #bab757;
    color: white;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#peerless:hover {
    background-color: #dcdbab;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
   <div id="tabTopBar">
        <div class="tabTop">
            <a id="armory" href="#armory" class="active">Armory</a>
            <a id="peerless" href="#peerless">Peerless</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Does not specifically need JavaScript to solve this.  Create a SNIPPET of your code with at least 2-3 examples of the "blocks" to allow a proper answer here.  Certainly try to get away from the ID use in the CSS here and use classes.

Comment: To clarify, which gray container do you want to follow the child color? Is it `.tabTop` or `tabTopBar`? Also, you might want to remove `pointer-events:none` and use the `cursor` property instead.

Comment: You Can Do that either with JavaScript or css. If you want to use css and detect a click in an element you will need to use a checkbox. Then check if the parent has the checkbox checked with :has() selector to change color

Comment: Hi -- to answer your questions I added a bit more code and included the snippet. 

The IDs are there to differentiate the links because I found no other way to individually color the a class bgs.
the pointer-effect: none is there because i wanted to prevent the hover effect on the active link. 

I hope this suffices and helps with problem solving.

This honestly could be a case of me being a total noob and stupid

Comment: if you set a link to the a tag how can you see the color of the parent div?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I don't quite see how ids can be got rid of here seeing as they are being used as the destination for the anchor elements. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @AHaworth Sorry for the delay. with the CSS we can create some generic classes to apply to multiple groups rather than singular ID's thus less CSS overall for the style.  Style does not have to directly follow the functional part as you denote on the anchors.  Closed question so harder to "show" vs "tell" here

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss ah yes, agreed. I’d misinterpreted you to mean get rid of the ids.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, use `getComputedStyle` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)) to get the background color of the element and then set the bar to that color. Example below.

Note: I've had to remove the `pointer-events:none` from your CSS to allow the event to trigger.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  document.querySelector('#tabTopBar').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const elementBackgroundColor = getComputedStyle(event.target).backgroundColor;
    document.querySelector('.tabTop').style.backgroundColor = elementBackgroundColor;
  });
}
```

```css
#tabTopBar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.tabTop {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
}

.tabTop a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#armory.active {
  background-color: #0e343d;
  color: white;
}

#armory:hover {
  background-color: #879a9e;
  color: black;
}

#peerless.active {
  background-color: #bab757;
  color: white;
}

#peerless:hover {
  background-color: #dcdbab;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="tabTopBar">
  <div class="tabTop">
    <a id="armory" href="#armory" class="active">Armory</a>
    <a id="peerless" href="#peerless">Peerless</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('.tabTop')` not going to work past 1 element group.

Comment: The author could use .closest() if that was an issue.

Comment: Perhaps to clarify for others `document.querySelector('.tabTop')` vs `this.querySelector('.tabTop')` to use the context of the element where the event is attached. for example in your code `this` is not that element defined but event is so `event.currentTarget.querySelector('.tabTop')` OR as you say `event.target.closest('.tabTop')`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use css as mentioned in comments above. Using the powerfull :has() css selector you can select a child element with class or id and give it the style you want if the a tag is focused (you can use also visited..)

```css
#tabTopBar {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

.tabTop {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: gray;
}

.tabTop a {
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

#armory.active {
    background-color: #0e343d;
    color: white;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#armory:hover {
    background-color: #879a9e;
    color: black;
}

#peerless.active {
    background-color: #bab757;
    color: white;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#peerless:hover {
    background-color: #dcdbab;
    color: black;
}

/* below are the lines added using the has() selector*/

#tabTopBar:has(a#armory:focus) .tabTop{  
    background-color: #879a9e;
}

#tabTopBar:has(a#peerless:focus) .tabTop{
    background-color: #bab757;
}
```

```html
<div id="tabTopBar">
    <div class="tabTop">
        <a id="armory" href="#" class="active" >Armory</a>
        <a id="peerless" href="#">Peerless</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The element will lose focus if for example there is an input somewhere else. So the color will not be maintained to indicate which anchor element was originally selected.

Comment: @A Haworth you are absolutely right but it also has to be inside the tapTopBar.

Comment: @A Haworth you are again absolutely right just checked and it easily loses focus if clicked somewhere else